# How do I move a floating point constant into an FP register?

Tags: assembly, floating-point, arm64, neon, immediate-operand

So, I am programming in assembly form ARM using the A64 instruction set.
I am using the instruction fmov   d1, #31.0 to move values to the dx register.
However, when I use 0.0 or any value higher than 31.0, it shows the error:

```
"Error: invalid floating-point constant at operand 2 -- `fmov d1,#32.0'"
```

So, how do I define a floating-point constant on A64? Why can't I use any value above 31 or use 0? How can I represent the values in hex?

Another question is: According to the [arm's website](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/learn-the-architecture/aarch64-instruction-set-architecture/registers-in-aarch64-general-purpose-registers) it supports the use of floating point registers as Bx, Hx, Sx, Dx and Qx (8,16 ,34,64 and 128 bits respectively), but I just can't use the Bx,Hx and Qx registers, it shows:

" Error: operand mismatch -- `fmov b1,#1.0'"

" Error: selected processor does not support `fmov h1,#2.0"

" Error: operand mismatch -- `fmov q1,#2.0'"

How can I properly set the second operand?

Answer (score 11):

Only a very small set of floating point constants can be used with `fmov` because the constant is encoded as an 8 bit immediate in the instruction.  Specifically, it must be representable as ±*n*/16×2<sup>*r*</sup> where *n* is an integer in the range 16 ≤ *n* ≤ 31 and *r* is an integer in the range of −3 ≤ *n* ≤ 4.

The exact list of supported numbers is given in the *ARMv8 Architecture Reference Manual.*  Additionally, `fmov` is only available for 16, 32, and 64 bit data sizes as no 8 bit or 128 bit floating point formats are specified for ARMv8.  For ARMv8 cores not supporting `FEAT_FP16`, a 16 bit data size is not supported either.  ARMv8 lacks orthogonality in quite a few places like this; not all instructions are available with all operand sizes.

For a simple alternative solution, use `ldr` with a constant in a literal pool instead (which you need to manually translate into an integer).  For example, to load `32.0`, translate `32.0` into its IEEE 754 representation, giving you `0x4040000000000000`.  You can then load this constant like this:

```
ldr d1, =0x4040000000000000
```

The `ldr` instruction with SIMD&FP register and a value in a literal pool is available with operand sizes 32 bit, 64 bit, and 128 bit.  Smaller operand sizes are not available for literal-pool addressing modes.  If you want to load an 8 or 16 bit register, load the corresponding 32 bit register instead.

A slightly faster solution is to first load the desired number into a general purpose register (which support more flexible generation of immediates) and then to move it into a SIMD&FP register:

```
mov x0, #0x4040000000000000
fmov d1, x0
```

To load `0.0` or masks, use the `movi` instruction.  The set of legal immediates for this instruction depends on the operand size.  But for your case, this would just be

```
movi d1, #0
```

This clears the `d1` register (and thus the `b1`, `h1`, `s1`, and `q1` registers, too).

Comment: so let me see if I got it straight: I really can't load a number bigger than 31 directly to the floating point register?

Comment: @MarlonPedersoli You can do so directly using `ldr`.  The `fmov` instruction does support other numbers bigger than 31.0 (such as 32.0), as long as they fit into the set of directly loadable numbers given in the first paragraph.

Comment: Tried with AOSP llvm clang but it either complains about the immediate too large or invalid operand as follows:
`error: Immediate too large for register`
`ldr d1, =0x4040000000000000`
`error: invalid operand for instruction`
`ldr d1, =0x40400000`

Comment: @Farley That's unfortunate.  Seems like the clang assembler has a bug here.  This assembles fine with the GNU assembler.

Answer (score 1):

I'm way late to the party here, but I (an amateur) figured out how to load floating point numbers into registers using .data. Here is my sample code for printing PI. I hope it helps someone else as I spent about two hours trying to figure it out myself. -- Jds

```
.global main
.align 4


main:
    ADRP    X1, pi@PAGE         // Load the address for our "pi" data
    ADD X1, X1, pi@PAGEOFF
    LDR D1, [X1]                // Store the contents of X1 to D1

    STR D1, [SP, #-16]!         // Store the float (D1) onto the stack for printing
    ADRP    X0, format@PAGE     // Load the address of our printf format string
    ADD X0, X0, format@PAGEOFF

    
end:
    BL  _printf                 // print -- reads string from X0 and data from stack
    mov X16, #1
    svc 0



.data
    pi: .double 3.141519
    format: .asciz  "Pi is %f \n"
```

Comment: You can do it this way, but it's faster to just use a literal pool load.  If you don't want to do that, you can at least do `LDR D1, [X1, pi@PAGEOFF]` to save yourself the `ADD` instruction.